# my tabs dont work what should i do (android app eclipse)

Tags: android-layout, tabs

i am using eclipse to make an android app and i have added tabs to it but when i run the app all of the stuff in the tabs overlap onto one page how can i fix this, here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TabHost
                    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TabWidget
                            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:showDividers="middle"
                            android:tabStripEnabled="true" >

                        </TabWidget>

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:text="@string/Lat" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:text="@string/Long" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:text="@string/Alt" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView01"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                    android:text="@string/Current_Lat" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_above="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView06"
                                    android:text="@string/Current_Long" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView07"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView05"
                                    android:text="@string/Current_Alt" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                    android:text="@string/Speed" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
                                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
                                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView07"
                                    android:text="@string/Current_Speed" />

                                <Button
                                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:text="@string/start" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

also i am trying to put a map into my app, how would i go about doing this?